# Redis wrong "used_memory_human" on Sentinel Slave

Tags: redis, node-redis

A slave node reports:

```
redis-cli -p 7001 info memory | grep used_memory
used_memory:10741368904
used_memory_human:10.00G
```

With no keys:

```
redis-cli -p 7001 info Keyspace
# Keyspace
```

It's master reports the correct size:

```
# Memory
used_memory:4963584
used_memory_human:4.73M
```

Persistence files have all the same size on every server:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 178 Feb 28 17:43 /var/lib/redis/dump_7001.rdb
```

Actions taken: on the Slave the .rdb file was deleted and redis restarted. Master-Slave synced ok but still reporting the difference. 
Failovered but didn't solve it.

```
jira@fr4redistaskmp03:~$ redis-cli -h redistaskmp01 -p 7001 info memory  | grep  used_memory_human
used_memory_human:4.73M

jira@fr4redistaskmp03:~$ redis-cli -h redistaskmp02 -p 7001 info memory  | grep  used_memory_human
used_memory_human:4.77M

jira@fr4redistaskmp03:~$ redis-cli -h redistaskmp03 -p 7001 info memory  | grep  used_memory_human
used_memory_human:10.00G

jira@fr4redistaskmp03:~$ redis-cli -h redistaskmp03 -p 7001 info replication
# Replication
role:slave
master_host:172.25.8.17
master_port:7001
```

Any idea?

The complete output:
The bad one:

```
redistaskmp03:~$  redis-cli -p 7001 info memory
# Memory
used_memory:10741368904
used_memory_human:10.00G
used_memory_rss:6864896
used_memory_rss_human:6.55M
used_memory_peak:10741430888
used_memory_peak_human:10.00G
used_memory_peak_perc:100.00%
used_memory_overhead:10741311316
used_memory_startup:3658312
used_memory_dataset:57588
used_memory_dataset_perc:0.00%
allocator_allocated:10741442744
allocator_active:10741768192
allocator_resident:10751008768
total_system_memory:135206285312
total_system_memory_human:125.92G
used_memory_lua:37888
used_memory_lua_human:37.00K
used_memory_scripts:0
used_memory_scripts_human:0B
number_of_cached_scripts:0
maxmemory:10737418240
maxmemory_human:10.00G
maxmemory_policy:noeviction
allocator_frag_ratio:1.00
allocator_frag_bytes:325448
allocator_rss_ratio:1.00
allocator_rss_bytes:9240576
rss_overhead_ratio:0.00
rss_overhead_bytes:-10744143872
mem_fragmentation_ratio:0.00
mem_fragmentation_bytes:-10734483056
mem_not_counted_for_evict:0
mem_replication_backlog:10737418240
mem_clients_slaves:0
mem_clients_normal:234764
mem_aof_buffer:0
mem_allocator:jemalloc-5.1.0
active_defrag_running:0
lazyfree_pending_objects:0
```

The good one:

```
    # Memory
used_memory:4963584
used_memory_human:4.73M
used_memory_rss:4591616
used_memory_rss_human:4.38M
used_memory_peak:5168376
used_memory_peak_human:4.93M
used_memory_peak_perc:96.04%
used_memory_overhead:4908920
used_memory_startup:3658352
used_memory_dataset:54664
used_memory_dataset_perc:4.19%
allocator_allocated:4993456
allocator_active:5312512
allocator_resident:10412032
total_system_memory:135206285312
total_system_memory_human:125.92G
used_memory_lua:37888
used_memory_lua_human:37.00K
used_memory_scripts:0
used_memory_scripts_human:0B
number_of_cached_scripts:0
maxmemory:10737418240
maxmemory_human:10.00G
maxmemory_policy:noeviction
allocator_frag_ratio:1.06
allocator_frag_bytes:319056
allocator_rss_ratio:1.96
allocator_rss_bytes:5099520
rss_overhead_ratio:0.44
rss_overhead_bytes:-5820416
mem_fragmentation_ratio:0.94
mem_fragmentation_bytes:-309056
mem_not_counted_for_evict:0
mem_replication_backlog:1048576
mem_clients_slaves:0
mem_clients_normal:201992
mem_aof_buffer:0
mem_allocator:jemalloc-5.1.0
active_defrag_running:0
lazyfree_pending_objects:0
```

redis_version:5.0.4

Maybe a bug?

Comment: Check `info replication` please.

Comment: All good. All synced. The difference still there. Any idea? This is definitively wrong, although don't know how to reproduce. There are 15 other small redis instances on those servers. None is wrong.

Comment: I meant, include that information in your post.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. 
The problem was "repl-backlog-size 10gb" on .conf file.